# How to emulate "prefers-color-scheme" CSS media feature with "Emulation.setEmulatedMedia" before first load of page? (Selenium)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I need to emulate "prefers-color-scheme" CSS media feature and Sec-CH-Prefers-Color-Scheme header in Chrome. But when I execute "Emulation.setEmulatedMedia" command of Chrome DevTools Protocol using Selenium, color scheme is changed only after second load of the page. Is it possible to emulate CSS media features before first load?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setEmulatedMedia", {"features": [{"name": "prefers-color-scheme", "value": "dark"}]})
sleep(5)

driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending")
# First load of the page. Emulation.setEmulatedMedia does nothing
# Browser sends "SEC-CH-PREFERS-COLOR-SCHEME: light"
# matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches -> true
# matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches -> false

driver.refresh()
# Second load of the page. Color scheme was changed
# Browser sends "SEC-CH-PREFERS-COLOR-SCHEME: dark"
# matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)').matches -> false
# matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches -> true
```

Chrome Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.64

Comment: Sounds like a bug in CDP. Try creating an empty target, set emulation, navigate the target.